# ee.List to FeatureCollection to be exported as a CSV?

Tags: google-earth-engine, csv

I'm trying to find the method to convert an ee.List to a FeatureCollection in order to be exported as a CSV file.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour].  What exactly is your question?  What have you tried, and what was the result?  Please [edit] your post to include an actual question, and detail what you've already tried.

Answer (score 1):

To convert an `ee.List` of features to an `ee.FeatureCollection`, you just write `ee.FeatureCollection(list)`. If you have an `ee.List` of non-features, you will need to `.map()` over it to convert each element to a feature (with one property per column you wish to export).